# While storing pdf text in csv how to avoid spreading text to multiple row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, pypdf

I am storing pdf text (extracted with pypdf) in a CSV file. the problem is few pdf file is very long and the text spreads into multiple rows for those long pdf file instead of keeping a single row. How to keep them in a single row? here my output looks like

```
column1    column2            
 long pdf    hello my
             name is jhone
 short pdf   hello my name is jhone. I haven't any problem for short pdf file
```

my code:

```
pdf_url ='https://www.snb.ch/en/mmr/speeches/id/ref_20230330_amrtmo/source/ref_20230330_amrtmo.en.pdf'
print("pdf_url: ",pdf_url)
   
# Download the PDF file from the URL
response = requests.get(pdf_url)

# Create an in-memory buffer from the PDF content
pdf_buffer = io.BytesIO(response.content)

# Read the PDF file from the in-memory buffer
pdf = PdfReader(pdf_buffer)
pdf_content = []
# Access the contents of the PDF file
for page_num in range(len(pdf.pages)):
    page = pdf.pages[page_num]
    page = str(page.extract_text())
    pdf_content.append(page)
    
   
   
with open(filename, "a", newline="",  encoding='utf8') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow([first_author, new_date_str, speech_title,pdf_url,pdf_content])

pdf_content.clear()
```

Comment: Hi ! Have you tried removing the newlines from the pdf text ? 
Additionally, could you please provide a runnable code ? As it is, your code can't be run, so it's very difficult to help.

Comment: my above code is working and yes also tried

Comment: Your code contains no imports, so I have no idea what modules you're using (I can guess, but that's not ideal, since I may be wrong). Plus, `filename`, `first_author`, `new_date_str` and `speech_title` are not defined. :/

Comment: @Hoodlum they are defined. here given  my partial code and I don't want to paste here my thousand lines of code

Comment: The reason I ask for a runnable code is so that I can run it to try and help you. If I have to guess how to make your example runnable, that's a bit of a waste of time and can introduce new bugs or misunderstandings. You don't need to paste thousands of lines of code - a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is enough.

Comment: you  can just remove undefined variable [first_author, new_date_str, speech_title] and code will be working. My partial code also  100% runnable

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this might be a limitation of your CSV reader, rather than a problem in your script: if you're using MS Excel (like I am), you'll find it has a maximum number of characters it can store per cell (see [the specs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us#ID0EBABAAA=Excel_2016-2013) )

When I check the length of the last string in the line, I find it to be just under this limit. Why this results in a new line is unclear to me though.

#### Work Around

To get around this limitation (in Excel), you can use the '*From CSV*' option to explicitly tell excel to import the data as a table. This should then display correctly.

Comment: can u show me how to use From CSV?

Comment: The easiest way is to type '*From CSV*' in the search bar in Excel. Otherwise, you'll find it under *Data > Get & Transform Data > FromText/CSV*. This opens a wizard. Then open your CSV file here.